# Xen 4.4: "/usr/lib/xen-4.4/bin/qemu-dm" is not executable

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I have a Debian server on which runs Xen 4.4. I want to crete a new Windows 7 virtual machine and install it from ISO image. This is the config file which I use for this:

```
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen-4.4/boot/hvmloader"

builder = 'hvm'

name = "win7"
uuid = "44dee145-256a-4450-9270-73aebd8b64a5"
memory = 2048
vcpus = 1
on_poweroff = "destroy"
on_reboot = "restart"
on_crash = "restart"

disk = [
         'phy:/dev/vg0/win7-demo-disk,hda,w',
         'file:/tmp/Win7.iso,hdc,r,devtype=cdrom',
       ]

vif = [ "mac=00:16:3e:46:e6:fb,bridge=br0" ]
boot="dc"
vnc = 1
vnclisten = "0.0.0.0"
vncunused = 1
localtime = 1
vncpasswd = "XXXXXXXX"
```

I execute this commad: xl create win7.cfg

It prins the following errors:

```
Parsing config from win7.cfg
WARNING: ignoring "kernel" directive for HVM guest. Use "firmware_override" instead if you really want a non-default firmware
libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:1250:libxl__spawn_local_dm: device model /usr/lib/xen-4.4/bin/qemu-dm is not executable: No such file or directory
libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:1388:device_model_spawn_outcome: (null): spawn failed (rc=-3)
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1186:domcreate_devmodel_started: device model did not start: -3
libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:1484:kill_device_model: unable to find device model pid in /local/domain/395/image/device-model-pid
libxl: error: libxl.c:1421:libxl__destroy_domid: libxl__destroy_device_model failed for 395
```

In the **/usr/lib/xen-4.4/bin/** directory I do not have **qemu-dm** file. I have read on Debian forun the **qemu-dm** was removed from the Xen 4.4. Previously I have Xen 4.1. For this version the **qemu-dm** exeists and stores in the **/usr/lib/xen-4.4/bin/qemu-dm**

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this question would have better fitted on https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 5):

`/usr/lib/xen-4.4/bin/qemu-dm` seems to be a calculated path, but as you mentioned, it points to no existing file in Debian 8 Jessie.

What helped me with only using Debian 8 on-board resources:

- Install `qemu-system-x86`. (Not sure if this is really necessary.)
- Remove the `kernel = …` line from the DomU configuration file. (To silence the warning that this line will be ignored.)
- Add a line `device_model_version="qemu-xen"` to the DomU configuration file. (This is probably the main thing to do to get it working again.)

Found out empirically after skimming through [this thread on the xen-users mailing list](https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-users/2013-12/msg00013.html).